# TYPO3 Get URL parameters in PHP controller

Tags: typo3, url-parameters

How do I get the `url parameters` in my PHP code in TYPO3?

I have link like this

```
<f:link.page pageUid="138" additionalParams="{myname: Lilly}">Click!</f:link.page>
```

The page has a controller attached to it, now how do I get the value of the passed parameter to my controller?

I will have to render `Views` according to the parameter passed.

**EDIT**

I'm not sure how to go about this problem.

I have a controller which has actions `list` and `show`. If the `parameters` send to `show` action is `all`, then all the items should be displayed and similarly the `view` changes basing on the parameters passed.

My Question is :

1. How do I pass the parameters and how to catch them in the Controller?
2. The link to the action controller is showing really long, and looks very ugly. How do I customize the links? Is there something like `routes` through which I can achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to display all items on the show action? Isn't the list action supposed to do this?

Also, do i understand you right, that your plugin is inserted on multiple pages (one page for list view, another page for show view)? And do you use two plugins, or one?

Comment: I use only one plugin but different actions to render different types of views. In my application, the list action displays items with a limit and my show displays all items without any limit and with a different desgin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use the `f:link.action` Viewhelper. If you are in list action you could do something like this:

```
<f:link.action action="show" arguments="{myArgument: myArgument}">Link</f:link.action>
```

This should switch the view to the view of the show action.

If you would need to catch other arguments, you can `$this->request->getArguments()` to get all arguments, or `$this->request->getArgument('myArgument')` to get a specific argument in your controller. Note that this will only contain arguments, cleanly sent with a `f:link.action` Viewhelper, since those arguments are prefixed with the current extension / plugin you are using.

If you use RealURL, you could provide a configuration to rewrite your URL's to shorter ones.

Edit:

If your link needs to point to another page, you just have to add this:

```
<f:link.action action="show" arguments="{myArgument: myArgument}" pageUid="myId">Link</f:link.action>
```

Comment: Yes. Your solution will be applicable if I want to display the `list` and `show` views on the `same page`. But in my case, the `list` view is displayed on one page with uid 77 and `show` on another page with uid 87.

Comment: Just add "pageUid" to the link viewhelper, i have added an example to my post.

Comment: Awesome! You just saved me so much of time. Thank You :)

Comment: There's a typo here: Closing tag should be `</f:link.action>`.

Answer (score 1):

For fully automatic support of actions you would need to use `f:link.action` viewhelper however as you discovered yet - it creates too long sets of params (including controller etc.)

The best option in such case is mentioned `f:link.page` VH however you need to put more effort to find proper actions.

You have several options:

- If you want/can display these views on separate pages, just create two FE plugins, first will use `show` action as default one, second - `list` action. And then you can use simplified params.
- Use TypoScript for placing plugin on the page, in such case you can use  `bootstrap` your plugin with different default action - depending on TS conditions (if param x exist bootstrap with show, else with list)
- Use one action for both views, and render a standalone view as a result:

  ```
  public function show2Action() {
      $view = t3lib_div::makeInstance('Tx_Fluid_View_StandaloneView');
      if (t3lib_div::_GP('myname') == 'Lilly') {
          $view->setTemplatePathAndFilename(t3lib_extMgm::extPath('yourext') . '/Resources/Private/Templates/Some/Show.html');
          $view->assign('message', 'Hello ' . t3lib_div::_GP('myname'));
      } else {
          $view->setTemplatePathAndFilename(t3lib_extMgm::extPath('yourext') . '/Resources/Private/Templates/Some/List.html');
          $view->assign('message', 'Enter your name');
      }
      return $view->render();
  }
  ```

Don't forget to validate your data fetched with `_GP`.

Comment: Great! That's a nice approach. However, in the controller, instead of using `t3lib_div` we can use `$this->request->getArgument('show');`. But the problem is how do I check if the argument `show` has been set or not ?

Comment: No, you can't : arguments are taken from FULL param name tx_something[someelse]=foo - not from single GET params as you asked: ?name=Lilly, while using `link.page` instead of `link.action` you need to use `_GP`

Answer (score 1):

If you need more advanced view helpers, there's also the VHS extension
http://fedext.net/viewhelpers/vhs.html